# Necesito extraer el precio de un producto de un ArrayList

Tags: c#, array, arraylist

Tengo un problema al querer extraer el precio de un producto incluido en un `ArrayList` en c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace Proyecto_Nahuel_Salischiker
{
    class Program
    {

        ArrayList producto = new ArrayList();
        int numero = 5;
        int numero_precio = 5;
        int precio;
        public void productos()
        {

            foreach (string str in producto)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
        public void inicio()
        {
            producto.Add("|Categoria |" + " Producto | " + " Precio\n");
            producto.Add("1- |Golosina |" + " Chupetin | " + 50 + "\n");
            producto.Add("2- |Bebida |" + " Coca Cola | " + 30 + "\n");
            producto.Add("3- |Snack's |" + " Doritos | " + 45 + "\n");
            producto.Add("4- |Galletas |" + " Chocolina | " + 39 + "\n");
        }
        public void Agregar_Producto()
        {
            
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la categoria del producto a agregar(Golosina / Bebida / Snack's / Galletas");
            string Categoria_Nueva = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del producto: ");
            string Producto_Nuevo = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Precio del Nuevo Producto: ");
            int Precio_Nuevo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            producto.Add($"{numero}- |{Categoria_Nueva} |" + $" {Producto_Nuevo} | " + $"{Precio_Nuevo}\n");
            numero += 1;

        }
        public void Comprar_Productos()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            foreach (string str in producto)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese El numero del Producto que desea comprar");
            int Numero_producto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Producto Elegido: " + producto[(Numero_producto)]);
            Console.WriteLine("Cuantas unidades Desea?");
            int unidades = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

pueden ver que en la variable `Precio_Nuevo` se almacena el valor que el usuario entra para el nuevo producto que se va a almacenar en la lista.

Lo que yo necesito, es que al llamar al método `Comprar_Productos`, pueda guardar en una variable el precio del producto que el cliente haya elegido en ese momento, para posteriormente poder calcular el precio a abonar! Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de guardar toda la información en una cadena y después intentar parsearlo, podrías almacenar la información de cada producto usando una clase POCO. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Producto
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
        
       public string Categoria { get; set; }
    
       public string Producto { get; set; }
    
       public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    
   }
```

Teniendo la clase POCO definida, podrías empezar a usar una Lista de Productos para almacenar los productos disponibles:

```
List<Producto> productos = new List<Producto>();
```

Así, puedes acceder a cada uno de las propiedades de manera fácil. Puedes generar un objecto por cada producto que quieras añadir a la lista, y después agregarlo.

```
Producto prod = new Producto();
prod.id = 1;
prod.Categoria = "Golosina";
prod.Descripcion = "Chupetín";
prod.Precio = 50;

productos.add(prod);
```

Una vez tengas la lista de productos creada, lo único que necesitarías hacer para obtener la información del producto que quieras consultar es buscar el producto con el id correspondiente y consultar cada propiedad:

```
int id = 1; //El id a consultar
var p = productos.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("El precio del producto {0} con id {1} es: {2}", p.Descripcion, p.id, p.Precio));
```

EDIT:
Necesitarás agragar las siguentes referencias al principio:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Buena respuesta. Solo me queda la duda dado que la pregunta del op tiene pinta de ser un trabajo escolar o algo similar, por lo que es posible que no les permitan/hayan explicado linq/expresiones lambda.